# Does Apache Kafka provide a mechanism to track producers that have become unresponsive?

Tags: apache-kafka, heartbeat, producer

I am aware of how Kafka determines a *consumer* is "dead" and the generic support within the Kafka protocol for heartbeats (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-HeartbeatRequest)

In my case I'm specifically interested in accomplishing something similar with *producers*.

I am altering an existing application that presently submits data to another system. That application is being changed to submit events to a Kafka cluster. In addition to other kinds of messages, the application provides heartbeat messages. I could continue to do this, and instead send those heartbeat messages to a topic (probably a log compacted topic).

What I'm wondering is (a) does Kafka explicitly track producers, and (b) can I access this information, or (c) would I be better off simply having a topic dedicated to this purpose?

Comment: It would be good to clarify what type of producer you are trying to track. The answer is different depending on the type of producer I'd say (e.g. transactional vs. traditional)